# How do I send REST response to html in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

I am able to get data from the REST API in my application, i am able to print the data on to the console, but no idea how do i display on to html, can any one help me on this please?

App.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './employee';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'emp-data-example';
  employees:Employee[]=[];
  constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http:HttpClient){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/all").subscribe(
    response=>{
      this.employees=response; // here is error because response is an Object and employees is an array
    });
    //resp.subscribe((data)=>{this.employees=data});
    
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Emp Id</th>
      <th>Emp Name</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ngFor="let employee of employees">
      <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
      <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
      <td>{{employee.department}}</td>
      <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: try this `this.employees=[response];`

Comment: No its saying,The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Employee': id, name, department, salaryts(2696)

Comment: so can you show your response object?

Comment: [{"id":0,"name":"sudheer","department":"IT","salary":12344.0},{"id":23,"name":"kumar","department":"ECE","salary":12345.0}] is the response i am getting from REST and same only printing on console.

Comment: if this is the response, your code should work. But make sure your `Employee` model has the properties

Comment: And also an `asterisk (*)` is missing in your `ngFor`. It should be like this `*ngFor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are getting array in the response and its from an employee type it should be something like that:

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/all").subscribe(
(response: Array<Employee>) =>{
  this.employees = response;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I really appreciate your work.

Comment: any time. this should work event without the casting, but you should always check the combability between the receiving object from the API and the assigned object inside the component/service. if you'll try putting an array inside an regular object, you'll get errors and vise versa

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the type of the response to Employee and add it to your array like so:

```
    this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/all").subscribe(
    (response: Employee[]) =>{
      this.employees.push(...response);
    });
```

Comment: I have added the above code, but in console its saying ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. can you please tell me whats wrong with app.component.html ?

Comment: this is not compatible with the response he described . the response is an array of employees as is the employees object. here you are trying to push an array into array.

Comment: then: 

    (response: Employee[]) =>{
      this.employees.push(...response);

Comment: @misha1109 this would work, but it's not that most elegant way.

Comment: @vladkatz seems almost identical your answer, i prefer to push to the array in case the http request will not only happen onInit